# MongoDB closes connection after $text $search-query

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, full-text-search

I got the weird behaviour of my mongodb (which runs on a Raspberry PI V4 (4GB)) that the connection is closed as soon as i execute my { $text: { $search:  } } query without any special exception (cannot receive error only).

I got the following example datasets:

```
  { "cc": "AD", "n": "Sant Julià de Lòria", "la": 42.46372, "lo": 42.46372 },
  { "cc": "AD", "n": "Pas de la Casa", "la": 42.54277, "lo": 42.54277 },
  { "cc": "AD", "n": "Ordino", "la": 42.55623, "lo": 42.55623 },
  { "cc": "AD", "n": "les Escaldes", "la": 42.50729, "lo": 42.50729 },
```

inserted in a collection called "addresses". After that i've created an index on the propety 'n' to make it searchable.

```
> db.addresses.createIndex({ n: "text"})  
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

The index-creation is executed successfully but when i execute my query i got the following output:

```
> db.addresses.find({ "$text": { "$search": "Berlin" } })
2020-04-01T23:19:18.507+0200 I NETWORK  [js] DBClientConnection failed to receive message from 192.168.0.100:27017 - HostUnreachable: Connection closed by peer
2020-04-01T23:19:18.508+0200 I NETWORK  [js] DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Error: error doing query: failed
2020-04-01T23:19:18.510+0200 I NETWORK  [js] trying reconnect to 192.168.0.100:27017 failed       
2020-04-01T23:19:20.528+0200 I NETWORK  [js] reconnect 192.168.0.100:27017 failed failed 
>
```

The mongodb runs on port 27017 (default) on the Raspberry pi which has the following IP (192.2.0.100). I execute the query using a mongo-cli from a remote-pc

After the connection-close i have to restart the docker-daemon to be able to reconnect, otherwise the connection is refused by the mongodb.

Other queries work without any problems.

Comment: did the mongod log anything about that connection?

Comment: I just checked my mongodb log and it seems like there was nothing logged even if i set  this file as the logfile in the mongo-conf